# $A.getCallback() Error

Tags: lightning-record-page, lightning-app-builder, spring22

Receiving this error when adding a new tab to my lightning record page.
Any insight on how I can fix this?

Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'alternateExpressionValue')]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a custom component on this page ? or any custom component which uses this attribute `alternateExpressionValue`

Comment: There's a Lightning Component (aura, not LWC) trying to set an attribute called 'alternateExpressionValue' on an object that is turning up as undefined in your code base. If you can, search for alternateExpressionValue in your code base and share that code here and I think we can dig into the issue more

Answer (score 0):

Update: This has now been *fixed*

---

There is a known issue for this with a scheduled fix for Spring '22 Patch 10.0

[Error while making changes in the Lightning App Builder](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p4V000002nBGb)

As noted in the workaround, this doesn't end up blocking you from making/saving changes. You can continue making changes and saving them once you close the error dialog pop up.

> The changes made are still reflected when the user clicks the 'OK'
> button on the error dialog. Users can click the 'OK' button and
> proceed with saving the changes made.